# ImageMagick Errors while installing dependencies

Tags: snow-leopard, software, install

I'm using this script:
https://github.com/maddox/magick-installer

to install imagemagick and it's dependencies
i have a few errors the first run for some missing files or borken links but now i have all this solved.... but when it's installing the libpng, i think, the scrip stops and trow this error:

`ln: ./libtool: File exists`

i don't know what to do, seems like the first run it created some symlink somewhere and not it found this symlink and stops the script.

thanks.

Comment: had to comment one line on the script, once that creates the symbolic link

Answer (score 1):

Try installing ImageMagick with HomeBrew

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

Once installed just type

```
brew install imagemagick
```

This will download any dependancies, compile the source and install it.

More info here : http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/homebrew-os-xs-missing-package-manager/